# Matching 2 matrices of different sizes (matlab)

Tags: matlab, performance, matrix, size, match

I have 2 matrices (D:76572x2 and E:1850092x7) and want the values of rows in the larger matrix (E) if the the first two columns are equal to any row of the smaller matrix (D).

Example:

```
D = [1000 19751231;
     1000 19761231]

E = [1234 19701130 4 5 2 9 3;
     1000 19751231 2 3 2 5 2]
```

So in that case I only want the row: `[1000 19751231 2 3 2 5 2]` from matrix E. How can I compute this relatively quickly for a large matrix without using any/many (for-)loops?

Thanks

Comment: How can two columns be equal when they are different lengths? From your question `D` has 76572 rows and `E` has 1850092.

Comment: I updated the question, it should be values in the columns and not the entire columns.

Comment: "are equal to the values of the columns in the smaller matrix(D)" Do you mean "are equal to *any row* in the smaller matrix(D)"?

Comment: That is correct. Apologies for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `ismember` function here

```
rows_E = ismember(E(:,1:2),D,'rows');
```

From your example:

```
>> E(rows_E,:)
```

Yields

```
ans = 
    1000  19751231  2  3  2  5  2
```

Comment: Works! What a great solution!